# Calculating Log and Exp of a value using Apache Commons

Tags: java, math, apache-commons-math

I have a mortality risk calculation that requires the determination of natural logs and exp decay.  The method is detailed below.  I am curious to know why the methods for calculating exp etc are not static and if I use a single Log (or Exp) object for multiple arguments if there is a risk of incorrect calculations.  That is can I use a single instance of Log to calculate Log (2.3) and Log (567)?

```
public Double getROD(Integer score) {

        Double beta0 = new Double(-7.7631);
        Double beta1 = new Double(0.0737);
        Double beta2 = new Double(0.9971);

        Log log = new Log();
        Exp exp = new Exp();

        Double logit = beta0 + (beta1 * score) + (beta2 * log.value(new Double(score + 1)));
        Double mortality = exp.value(logit) / (1 + exp.value(logit));

        return mortality;
    }
```

I have tried the following:

```
Log log = new Log();

Double arg1 = log.value(new Double(12.3));
Double arg2 = log.value(new Double(29.12));

System.out.println(arg1.toString() + " : " + arg2.toString());
```

which results in

```
2.509599262378372 : 3.3714252233284854
```

However, there is still a question as to this being the intended behaviour across all uses.

Comment: I should have added that I have tried that and the results are consistent, however does not necessarily mean that the class will always behave that way.  I am also interested in the reasons for not using static methods.

Comment: Mostly, par design. Other libraries such as `GSON` also favors instances for operations instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Exp`, `Log`, etc. classes store no state. The reason their `value` methods are not static is to fulfil the `UnivariateFunction` interface. So, yes, you can safely reuse the objects.

One of the nice things about the `UnivariateFunction` interface is that you can write a function that takes such an object, and the user can parameterise your function by passing in an appropriate function object. This concept is called [higher-order functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) (if you come from the [FP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) camp, as I do) or [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) (if you come from the [OOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) camp).

Comment: Thank you - this is really appreciated.  There needs to be a level of confidence in calculating risk of death!

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to calculate the log and exp of a value it is usually better to use FastMath which provides static method for this and other basic mathematical functions (similar to Math but providing a pure java implementation and being faster for some of them).